# Empty space to the far right of header

Tags: html, css

There's empty space to the far right of a header I'm using on all pages. When the window is maximized, the header extends all the way to the right, but when the window is resized smaller, the empty space not only appears, but widens as the window is resized. `min-width: 100%` hasn't fixed this.

Here's the CSS. `.headerItem` has padding to it, and that was the initial culprit, but after removing all the padding, the space still persists.

```
.Header {
    height: 2.5rem;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #282828;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
    border-color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.Header a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

.headerItem {
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
    background-color: #232227;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: .65rem;
    padding-top: .25rem;
    padding-bottom: .25rem;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition-property: color;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    letter-spacing: .4rem;
    color: #D6A83D;
    border: solid 1px;
}

.headerItem:hover {
    transition: .25s;
    color: #ffec00;
    border-color: #ffec00;
    cursor:default;
}
```

All of the wrappers have also been reduced/edited to see if this would disappear, but it hasn't.

edit: Forgot the header

Comment: Please provide a working demo that shows your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer, a very simple one, too: the buttons wouldn't resize while the header would, so they extend past the header.

Comment: Please accept your own answer if you believe it is the right solution for your problem.